# web.com/post/post-title redirects to web.com/post-title

Tags: wordpress, url, permalinks, slug

I'm having a complain of the SEO guy because a post url is not like this

`web.com/blog/post-title`

But like this

`web.com/post-title`

And even `web.com/blog/post-title` redirects to `web.com/post-title`

How could I restore normal behavior? it looks like they are being treated as `page` but they work as posts in `web.com/blog`

Comment: Did you check your Permalink settings?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `%postname%` option

Comment: You want to add a prefix `post` to your URL structure?

Comment: Actually `blog`, but yes!  `web.com/blog/blog-title`

Comment: Tried this? Go to `Settings` -> `Permalink` Choose the Custom structure and fill the value with `/blog/%postname%/`

Comment: @ManojKumar Wouldn't that affect to pages, too?

Comment: I just checked, it didn't affect Pages.

Comment: I tried, but this throws 404 on existing posts...

Comment: @ManojKumar You can post it as an answer, i'll accept it.. i don't know how i tried, but it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Settings -> Permalink`

Choose the Custom structure and fill the value with `/blog/%postname%/`

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Just want to mention that i had never have to Do this so they work like this... but anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Need to update the htaccess inorder to get the old path works OR you can set the permalink is to /blog/%postname%/ like this

Please refer this link: 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19238/how-do-i-add-blog-as-a-prefix-to-permalink-structure-for-blog-posts-tag-pages

Comment: This looks more a comment than an answer... How Do you suggest I can Do that?

Comment: Check the above link for reference. That may help you